# Sign of correlation of logged variables

Tags: correlation

If we know that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated, do we know that the random variables $Z = \log(X)$ and $W = \log(Y)$ are positively correlated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, without any additional assumption, knowing the ([Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)) correlation on $X$ and $Y$ does not give any clue on the ([Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)) correlation between $\log X$ and $\log Y$. See the following example in R:

```
x1 = c(10^-100, 1, 10^5)
x2 = c(1, 10^-100, 10^5)

cor(x1, x2) # = 1
cor(log(x1), log(x2)) # -0.4251781
```

(Here, $X_1$ and $X_2$ can take $3$ values with equal probabilities $\frac{1}{3}$.)

Comment: +1 for the nice counter example.  But this would be clearer if you started with "No" rather than "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

We don't.

You can [calculate an approximation via Taylor Series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/covariance-of-transformed-random-variables/46930#46930) that should work fairly well for X and Y having a small coefficient of variation or being close to normal.