# Pearson correlation of one log-transformed variable

Tags: correlation, covariance, lognormal-distribution

Consider two $X$ and $Y$ that are bivariate lognormal. Is there a way to express $\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}\Cov(\log(X),Y)$ in terms of $\Cov(X,Y)$, even if an approximation must be made?

Comment: You can take a similar approach to what was done [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46930/805) applied to just one of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, @Glen_b ! I looked at that post and it was extremely helpful. The trick (which is awesome) doesn't seem to work here, because the trick relies on the properties of multiplying exponentials, and we only have one exponential here. Is this correct?

Comment: The taylor series referenced on wikipedia results in expressions such as $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{y}{x^2}\right]$, and I could not manipulate expressions like these to obtain $Cov(X,Y)$. Is there something I missed?

Comment: A more explicit answer below. I'll give an outline of one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ and $V$ be correlated random variables, which for the purpose of illustration will be taken to be bivariate normal. Assume they're standardized and have correlation (and hence covariance) $\rho$

$$
\operatorname{Cov}(U,exp(V)) = \operatorname{Cov}(U, 1+V+V^2/2!+V^3/3!+V^4/4!+...)
$$
$$
 = \operatorname{Cov}(U,V)
+\frac{1}{2!}\operatorname{Cov}(U, V^2)
+\frac{1}{3!}\operatorname{Cov}(U, V^3)
+\frac{1}{4!}\operatorname{Cov}(U, V^4)+...
$$

These are functions of $\rho$.

For unscaled variables you can write it in terms of the $\mu$'s, $\sigma$'s and these values.